# error starting xxxx: Module xxxx attempts to access a secure API

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have checked other questions around but no one seems to have exactly the same error.  I'm using phonegap+jqm to create an application, initially tested on my android phone, now i'm trying to build-deploy to a blackberry. To build the app i used the phonegap starting guide, with:

```
    ant blackberry load-device
```

I DID sign the application with the RIM provided keys. Still getting the error. Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Signing Tool + JAVA SDK 1.7: it is a known issue that these two dont get along well.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the BlackBerry Signature Tool and run your compiled .cod file through it to check whether it is really signed or not.